# CRM 2011: Is it safe to update the Prefix of existing publishers

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am working on a CRM 2011 system where we have 3-4 different publishers and some of them have default prefix ('new_'). To maintain the consistency I want to keep the same prefix for all publishers.

I know how to update the prefix. But my question is:

Is it safe to change the prefix of existing publishers? Does it have any impact on Entities and Attributes published by them?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Pick a publisher and delete the others. You can't change the names of entities and attributes anyway (unless you delete & re-create them), *unless* you dig in the CRM database, with the risk of making it non-functional

Comment: @Alex thanks. I know I can't change the names of entities and attributes and I am not going to touch them. Just want to make sure that if I delete a publisher or update it. does it going to cause any issue?

Comment: I believe not but I never did it so I don't have prior experience to back that up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I don't believe this will change any of your existing Entities.  If it does, it would be a simple call to change it back.

Comment: It does not change the existing customizations. It impacts only the modifications which are done afterwards.

Comment: @Daryl, thanks. I have already done that with the same thought that It will be straight forward to revert it back to previous prefix if needed.